# url reload with custom Number sign

Tags: php, html, url, redirect, mobile

We are making a website that has a desktop and mobile part

but we would like to use the same URL for both of them and depending on the user-agent load in the correct html/css

for the desktop part we are using Ember and its routing capabilities

so for instance: http://domain.com/#!/newsitems/news-item-1

for our mobile part we would like not to use JS for our routing but manual page refreshes ( so our mobile site works on as many different devices possible )

so if i want to make a button that redirects to "news-item-1"

```
<a href="#!/newsitems/news-item-1">link</a>
```

doesn't reload my page because it recognizes its Number sign.
Is there a possibility that i can refresh the page but still keep the url.

We would capture the URL in php and then display the correct html/css

Comment: I don't see a way... You certainly could catch the click event on the loop and do whatever you like, but you'd need script for that which is exactly what you do _not_ want. Ah,w ait... what about using absolute urls that _contain_ the `#`? You won't be able to relocate the site easily, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "fragment" of the URL is never passed to the server, it is stripped off by the browser for its own use. It is therefore impossible to directly read it in PHP.

What you can do instead is the opposite: for non-JS situations, the HTML should contain a normal URL like `<a href="/foo">...`. The JS can then enhance this by adding a #! as appropriate, dynamically changing the link to `<a href="#!/foo">...`

This general idea, that you write the simple code first and layer rich features on top, rather than embedding them in the code, is known as "progressive enhancement". It can be viewed as a solution to the problem of "graceful degradation", which is what you are trying to achieve in supporting as many platforms as possible.